# Make rest calls between two standalone spring boot apps

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to spring boot. I created an app that is able to access a service defined in it using CRUD operations. All tutorials explain the same. Now I have a remote app with which I want to make rest calls. I would like to know as how to make my app recognize the remote endpoint. How to define that app in my yaml or properties file and access its service. Pointing out to some relative tutorial would be very helpful.

Comment: You can refer to this tutorial of [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) on Spring official website.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to believe that you weren't able to find any useful information, but anyways here goes..

You can find some information on what you're searching for here:

http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet

```
//Imports
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

//Implementation
RestTemplate restTemplate = ContextProvider.getBean(RestTemplate.class);
ResponseEntity<ReturnType> data=null;

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

if(headers.isEmpty()){
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
}

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    put("<paramname>",<paramvalue>);                            
}};

ResponseEntity<ReturnType> data = restTemplate.exchange(<url>, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<Object>(params, headers), ReturnType.class);
```